# How to disable the popup boxes in chromium browser when mouse hover on the tabs in Ubuntu 16.0 System?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu, browser, chromium

I upgraded my chromium browser recently in Ubuntu 16.0 system, now it is displaying some un-necessary popup round circles on the browser tabs when mouse over on the tabs. Which is not looking good for me. 
How to disable the tab hover preview cards in the browser .

Following is the screenshot of the issue.[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: @jww , You are right, I will post this in other site, instead of here. Thank You

Answer (score -2):

Updated Chrome includes new tab tooltips (comes with new tooltip appearance for tabs. Now it looks like a flyout that includes the full page title and URL)and lot of changes.

If you want to disable them and restore the classic look of tooltips, you need to disable them with a flag.

1.Open the Google Chrome browser and type the following text in the address bar:

```
chrome://flags/#tab-hover-cards
```

2. Select the option Disable from the drop-down list next to the 'Tab Hover Cards' line.

3.Restart browser by closing it manually or you can also use the Relaunch button which will appear at the very bottom of the page.

4.You are done. This will restore the classic tab tooltips.